# How do I use Rails clockwork gem to run rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

What is the syntax for calling rake tasks from clockwork?  I've tried all kinds of syntax, and nothing seems to work. (I'm specifically interested in clockwork because Heroku's supporting it.)

Here's my clock.rb, using the same syntax that the whenever gem uses:

```
module Clockwork
  puts "testing clockwork!"
  every(30.seconds, 'Send Messages') {
    rake 'scheduler:send_messages'
    }
end
```

And here's my rake task in scheduler.rake:

```
task :send_messages => :environment do
  puts "rake task run successfully!"
end
```

And here's what happens when I start a clockwork process:

```
$ clockwork lib/clock.rb
testing clockwork!
I, [2012-07-16T14:42:58.107245 #46427]  INFO -- : Starting clock for 1 events: [ Send Messages ]
I, [2012-07-16T14:42:58.107364 #46427]  INFO -- : Triggering 'Send Messages'
attempting to run rake task!
E, [2012-07-16T14:42:58.107437 #46427] ERROR -- : undefined method `rake' for Clockwork:Module (NoMethodError)
```

This runs every 30 seconds.  As you can see, the clock.rb is executed successfully. But I can't for the life of me figure out the syntax to run a rake task. The clockwork readme is no help, unfortunately:

https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork

Comment: After browsing through clockworks readme, nowhere does it use the syntax you're using (`rake 'some:task`)

Comment: Yes, in fact it offers no examples of syntax at all. I've tried the cron syntax (rake some:task), and the whenever syntax (rake 'some:task') and no dice. Seeing as how the description reads "Clockwork is a cron replacement." you'd think that one of these would work.

Comment: Why not use the Heroku scheduler?

Comment: I will if I have to, but Heroku scheduler doesn't scale beyond a certain point, and I'd like to put something in place that can scale.

Comment: Also, I can't test Heroku scheduler on my development machine. I've tried using the whenever gem, but there's no instructions on how to use whenever on a development machine either.

Answer (score 10):

`rake` is not a method, so you can't invoke it like that here.

You can either shell out and invoke it, something like

```
every(30.seconds, 'Send Messages') {
  `rake scheduler:send_messages`
}
```

or rather invoke a new detached process using the heroku API. This is my preferred method right now:

```
Heroku::API.new.post_ps('your-app', 'rake scheduler:send_messages')
```

Heroku::API is available from heroku.rb: https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb

Comment: Ok, with that syntax there's no longer an error message, but it doesn't actually run the rake task.  I will definitely use the Heroku API when I deploy, but right now I need to do some testing on my local machine to make sure the database is being accessed correctly by the rake task. Thanks

Comment: you can invoke the rake task using `heroku run rake scheduler:send_messages` from your shell, and see any output your task prints to stdout. You possibly need a bundle exec in there, too

Comment: Just trying to get this to run on my local machine (OSX) for now.  When I run `$ bundle exec rake send_messages` from the project directory it runs the rake task correctly.  Why it's not running the rake task from Clockwork is a mystery.

Comment: what happens when you run `heroku run rake scheduler:send_messages`? This will run it on a heroku dyno, same as the `Heroku::API` method I proposed would

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm having a similar problem w/ the syntax: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465869/how-do-i-use-the-clockwork-rails-scheduler-gem)

Comment: This answer works!  But only if you use the **exact string syntax** used in the answer, `"rake my:task"` will not run the rake task but ` `rake my:task` ` will as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following method to your `clock.rb` file:

```
def execute_rake(file,task)
require 'rake'
rake = Rake::Application.new
Rake.application = rake
Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
load "#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/#{file}"
rake[task].invoke
end
```

and then call

```
execute_rake("your_rake_file.rake","your:rake:task")
```

in your handler

Comment: How would you execute a delayed_job rake task without having the file to reference?  E.g. `rake jobs:work`

Comment: @Kelseydh I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you ever figure out how to do that?

Comment: @webdevguy Might not be what you're looking for, but this is the answer that let me get rake tasks working with clockwork: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29340040/3448554

Comment: This answer by @PatrickNLT worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass in a block to `every` that executes your rake task:

```
every(1.day, "namespace:task") do
  ApplicationName::Application.load_tasks
  Rake::Task['namespace:task'].invoke
end
```

Comment: When using this approach remember to require your application.rb file: require_relative './application' (if clock.rb under config: config/clock.rb), this line should be stated outside module

Answer (score 1):

Invoking the task using `Rake::Task['...'].invoke` works well the first time, but the task need to be reenabled to be invoked again later.

```rb
    ApplicationName::Application.load_tasks

    module Clockwork do
        every(10.minutes, "namespace:task") do
          Rake::Task['namespace:task'].invoke
          Rake::Task['namespace:task'].reenable
        end
    end
```

Otherwise the task will be invoked the first time, but no more after that until the clockwork process is restarted.