# How do I use the Clockwork Rails scheduler Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, scheduled-tasks

I'm having problems with the syntax for the Clockwork scheduler process. I'm actually having similar issues to what is discussed in this thread but never fully answered([How do I use Rails clockwork gem to run rake tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513058/how-do-i-use-rails-clockwork-gem-to-run-rake-tasks))

My 'scheduler.rake' is working correctly when I test it with a 'heroku rake send_notifications'. My clock.rb process is working too as it will trigger every 30 seconds. However, I'm having issues with the clock.rb's syntax to correctly run the 'send_notifications' task in my 'rake.scheduler'. Here's what it looks like:

```
# scheduler.rake
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :send_notifications => :environment do

   puts "this test is working correctly!"

end
```

Here's what clock.rb looks like:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',        __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'clockwork'

include Clockwork

every(30.seconds, 'Send notifications') {
   # Heroku::API.new.post_ps('pocket-pal', 'rake scheduler:send_notifications')
    rake scheduler:send_notifications
}
```

As you can see I've tried with a detached process using the Heroku API and invoking rake.

When I use the Heroku API, I get this error:

```
ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Heroku (NameError)
```

When I invoke rake, I get the following error:

```
ERROR -- : undefined local variable or method `send_notifications' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Does anyone know what the correct syntax is for either approach?

Comment: add string quotes to rake scheduler:send_notifications

Comment: The task send_notifications is inside scheduler namespace?

Answer (score 6):

[This answer works,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11516026/3448554) however you need to follow its string syntax **exactly.**  So in your case:

```
every(30.seconds, 'Send Notifications') {
  `rake scheduler:send_notifications`
}
```

That means making sure to use `` ` ` `` for wrapping the rake task, not `" "` as that's tripped a few people up.

Answer (score 0):

The docs from Hereko on implementing clockwork might help

[Scheduled Jobs and Custom Clock Processes in Ruby with Clockwork](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes)

Comment: Should it be linked to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes instead?

Comment: @FábioMiranda Fixed it. They might have changed the url.